What is the difference between "root" and "dbmasteruser" login in aws lightsail?
I've encountered an issue while working with my AWS Lightsail database. I successfully created a new database named "test" using the root user credentials in phpMyAdmin. However, when I try to access this database using the dbmasteruser account, I'm unable to do so. Additionally, the dbmasteruser account doesn't appear in the User section of phpMyAdmin.
I'm attempting to access the database using phpmyadmin with dbmasteruser account.
I'm curious to know why this issue is occurring. Is there a specific permission setting or configuration that I need to adjust? Or is there a limitation with the dbmasteruser account that prevents it from accessing databases created by the root user?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Mate check it:

Accessing the Database with dbmasteruser


Grant Privileges: Run this in your database:
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON test.* TO 'dbmasteruser'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;


dbmasteruser Not Visible in phpMyAdmin


Check User and Run:
SELECT User, Host FROM mysql.user;



Lambda Function for Database Access


Network: Ensure Lambda has access to your Lightsail instance.

Connection Example (Node.js):
javascript
const mysql = require('mysql');
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
host: 'your-lightsail-db-endpoint',
user: 'dbmasteruser',
password: 'your_password',
database: 'test',
});
connection.connect();


